# How to measure the size of a C# program

Tags: c#

How to measure the size of a C# program?

Suppose I have

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
}
```

How to measure how many bytes the program has taken?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you could define what "how many bytes the program has taken" means in the first place. Before you can measure a quantity, you have to define it.

Comment: Do you need to take into account the size of the .NET Framework your program relies on?

Comment: Do you mean how many bytes in *memory* (RAM) or on the hard disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the size of the program's executable in bytes from inside your program:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
Console.WriteLine(fi.Length);
```

Otherwise you can just browse to the bin folder of your executable in explorer and see the size in file properties.

Answer (score 4):

Compile it and check the compiled file's size?

Answer (score 2):

When a program is compiled it will be an executable of a certain size. The more code the bigger the program will be.  When your program is run, the size is usually the amount of memory it is using during it's operation.

When the program is executed, the computer will allocate the memory to "load" program.  This load process may need other .Net framework DLLs or third party DLLs as needed.  The load process will usually consume a fairly consistent amount of memory when the program is first loaded.  How much memory depends on the program size and framework or third party DLLs.  .Net is good at loading things JIT (Just in Time), which means that some DLLs may not be loaded until they are needed.

During the course of running the program, .Net will allocate items to go on the stack.  As method and functions call each other, they are put on the stack, and when the method and function calls are over, the stack unwinds.  For example, a recursive function may put itself 100s of times on the stack and eventually run out of memory if the recursion is too deep.  This "stack" is dynamic allocation of memory and depends on the method and function calls your application makes.  The deeper the calls, the more items that are on the stack.  This will effect the size of memory used by the program.

The other piece of the puzzle is the heap.  Dynamic allocations are placed on the heap.  These are usually data structures that your program is currently using.  Because .Net has garbage collection, the .Net programmer does not have to worry about this memory management.  As items are placed on the heap and used, the size of your program (memory usage wise) grows, and then the garbage collection checks every so often to clean things up.  For example, you might have a program that reads in a 1 Gig XML file into memory.  Your program size might only be 30K, but since the entire file was read into memory, the size of your program is now over 1 Gig (memory wise).  One can use tools to monitor memory usage of a program to verify it is acting appropriately.  Most things in .Net are garbage collected, so one does not need to worry about the "size" of memory allocate (unless you are reading really large files into memory!), but unmanaged resources still need to be accounted for and cleaned up as needed.   Unmanaged resources examples are database connection, file handle etc.  .Net C# has a nice USING statement to automatically call Dispose to handle unmanaged resoures (Provided IDisposable is implemented) so as long as you are careful about this, your program should be free of any managed or unmanaged leaks.

All of these things contribute to the size of the program at compile time and at runtime.  The larger and more complex the program, typically the more size on disk and more memory usage at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
long size = fInfo.Length;
MessageBox.Show(size.ToString());
```

Comment: This will only work in windows forms. `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` works in both windows forms and WPF.